# Android Simple ListView getting refreshed automatically when row is selected

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to find the root of this below issue but not able to resolve this.

**Here is my code:**

```
   private ListView listViewRouteDownload;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.lyt_route_download);
                listViewRouteDownload = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRouteDownload);

                Object obj[]=routeDownloadHelper.routeInfo();
                beatId = (String[]) obj[0];
                beatName = (String[]) obj[1];
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RouteDownloadActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, beatName);
                listViewRouteDownload.setAdapter(adapter);
                listViewRouteDownload.setItemsCanFocus(false);

                listViewRouteDownload.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}
```

Everything in the above code works perfectly, **but** *`when I am selecting choices on by clicking on checkbox my the other rows of the listview gets refreshed automatically.`*

**Yes,** I can say that rows getting refreshed, see the example.
 If I have String 15 placed on the row, then by clicking on other row,the listview gets refreshed and make 15 as 1 `(and then below)` 5

**Here is the Screen shot when the listview loads for the first time.**

[image: When Loading]

**And here is the screen shot when I am clicking on the checkbox.**

[image: After Clicking]

you can see that **Second** image, there 22 becomes 2`(beolw that)`2.

**I want to resolve this issue.**

**Here is the layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRDTitle"
        style="@style/HeadingTheme"
        android:text="@string/route_sel" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewLine1"
        style="@style/horizontalImg"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewRDTitle" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBDRouteName"
                style="@style/ListViewHeaderTheme"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:text="@string/route" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewselparator1"
                style="@style/ListViewHeaderSeperatorEntry"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewBDRouteName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBDSelecct"
                style="@style/ListViewHeaderTheme"
                android:layout_width="87dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewselparator1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/select" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewRouteDownload"
                style="@style/ListViewTheme"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewBDRouteName"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRDBack"
            style="@style/styleNormalButton"
            android:text="@string/back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRDNext"
            style="@style/styleNormalButton"
            android:text="@string/next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks you.

Comment: can we see your simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml for the item ? I think its more likely a layouting issue...

Comment: this is not custom layout mate.this layout is provided by android. thats why it is written as android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice

Comment: oops ;) of course.. how embarassing ^^

Comment: Can you provide any solution for this issue I am facing or please upvoate this question so that others can take interest in this thread

Comment: can I see your listViewRouteDownload.xml, it's a long shot but maybe there is something worth investigating...

Comment: question update with the layout file

Comment: @Andac I have updated my question.please review it and let me know where i am wrong here

Answer (score 0):

try this xml, though I removed one "View" (line 7) you had there, you might want to replace it. 
This xml worked out fine for me, no errors, I guess the problem was you left out a lot of width-parameters? or they are included in your styles I dont see, but somewhere there you should finde the error:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRDTitle"
            style="@style/HeadingTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/route_sel" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewBDRouteName"
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderTheme"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/route" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewselparator1"
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderSeperatorEntry"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewBDRouteName" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewBDSelecct"
                    style="@style/ListViewHeaderTheme"
                    android:layout_width="87dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewselparator1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/select" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listViewRouteDownload"
                    style="@style/ListViewTheme"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewBDRouteName"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
                </ListView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRDBack"
                style="@style/styleNormalButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/back" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRDNext"
                style="@style/styleNormalButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/next" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please tell me if it worked out, maybe posting your styles or embetting the values into the layout.xml might help, there are a lot of values "hidden"...